# Why does "@username" become a link (but a different link in LQRQ)?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, old-answers

I'm really confused about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44736/6083675), which has the markup:

```
@Troels Arvin

I think we just sof'ed pragprog.com as I can't seem to connnect to it.

got one of these


>Network Timeout
>
>The server at www.pragprog.com is taking too long to respond.
>
>        
>The requested site did not respond to a connection request and the browser has stopped waiting for a reply.
>
>   * Could the server be experiencing high demand or a temporary outage?  Try again later.
```

It doesn't seem special, but currently, if it is clicked on, `@Troels Arvin` leads to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44667/6083675)...

... Unless you are in [the Low Quality Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13013270) of course. In that case, it links to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13013270#44667).

This is really more than one question:

1. Why is it a link in the first place? Were there no comments in 2008?
2. Why does it become a different (and wrong) link in the LQRQ?

Note: the link is gone because of edits, but I have this screenshot:

> [image: Linked!]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is a *very, very old* feature before commenting existed and answers were actually used to communicate with other users. The links use a hashtag identifier to link to the answer on the same page, like so:

```
<a href="#44667">Troels Arvin</a>
```

Obviously that won't work if the post gets displayed on a page where the other answer isn't actually on that page.

Posts no longer get rendered like this, and haven't since comments were implemented. These posts are simply still rendered as they were way back then because they haven't been edited since then to be re-rendered. Any edit will make that link disappear forever.

Comment: Ah legacy code.  Should have known.

Comment: This explains a number of poor answers (the ones that make you wonder: why not a comment?) that I've seen, many of which probably came from that "BC" era (before comments `:)`). I assume that this won't be fixed (except by editing, assuming it's an answer)?

Comment: @Laurel No, we don't forcibly re-render posts when we make changes to how things are rendered because a) there's no way to determine which ones actually need re-rendered, so it would be a forced re-render for *every* post and b) the changes could theoretically break the post, and no one would know - if someone has to do it manually, then they can fix it at the same time.

Comment: @animuson I was talking about the fact that the links in review are wrong. In a way, the system *is* rerendering the post, since the link changes.

Comment: How did [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-mysql#comment15092952_129) get posted before that answer?

Comment: @Laurel No, it's not. The link goes to `#44667`, which the browser changes to include the actual full URL. But the link itself defines an anchor meant to go to the element with that ID on the page, it's just that no such element exists in review. We're not displaying different content in two places, it's just that a relative link goes to different places depending on where it appears.

Comment: @yellowantphil It was an answer which was converted to a comment later (in 2012 actually).

Comment: Fascinating. I don't remember ever seeing this feature.

Comment: @animuson is that why the date in that comment is a link (back to the same comment)? I looked around briefly but found no other dates on comments which were links. Also, +yellowantphil I'm not sure which answer 'that answer' refers to.

Comment: @Rasta Comment date is always a link. In that case... it's just not colored grey, like any other comment dates. That's weird.

Comment: @nicael That would be the CSS. The links change color when you visit them, so you can change any of the date links from grey to blue.

Comment: @Laurel Nope, try with other comment dates and see yourself :)

Comment: @nicael I did, and it works as I said ... on the main site. Are you referring to meta? The visited color is just darker grey here.

Comment: @Laurel Uh oh, indeed you're right - checked with mobile. **But**, that links remain grey when using the Safari on Mac, strange.