# What was the content of the first comment ever posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments, stack-overflow-history

According to [this blog post from Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/16/new-improved-comments-with-reply/), the commenting feature was introduced on September 6, 2008:

> Stack Overflow didn’t always have post comments. The first comment ever was on [this post by Michael Stum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators/35314#35314), and it was posted on September 6th, 2008.

However, the comment seems to have been removed - the only comment on it was one posted on March of this year, and it seems that all the comments were cleaned up at an earlier time.

What was the content of that comment? Is it possible that it can be revealed?

(If you query the database, you may find earlier comments, but per the comments on [this global meta answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388167/377214), those all appear to be answers converted to comments, and the system backdates those comments' posting times to the time the answer was posted.)

Comment: It might be impossible to prove an answer to this - I don't think that deleted comments are (verifiably) persisted anywhere.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel mods have access to deleted comments

Comment: Except for curiosity  what is the purpose of  knowing *why it was deleted*. You don't dare to post a follow up question to get that comment undeleted, right?

Comment: @rene Um, no? As I said earlier in the post, I suspect it was deleted as part of a cleanup a while ago. The point of that question at the end is to confirm if that's the case. I'm also not going to push for the comment to be undeleted.

Comment: Comments before comments: [Why does "@username" become a link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328035/6083675)

Comment: Here's a link to that question from 2011 (Wayback machine): https://web.archive.org/web/20111105205659/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators/35314 doesn't seem to be anything interesting for the first comment though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The comment, by [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood), was:

> not sure why this is getting downvoted -- it is correct! Double check it in your compiler if you don't believe him!

These days, we'd probably remove such a comment as "No longer needed", *especially* on such a now-highly-voted answer (I'd guess that's why it was removed in 2018, though only the moderator who deleted it would know for sure).  But of course, it was a different time back then, and there wasn't quite so much experience moderating comments, largely due to the lack of any comments having ever been previously posted on the site.

Via [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat), you can [see the comment in context](https://web.archive.org/web/20111105205659/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301/what-is-the-diffference-between-the-and-or-operators/35314) via the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine.  Separately, I've confirmed that that is the first comment that appears on that post for a moderator viewing deleted comments.

Comment: Also noting that that comment was the *only* comment removed by that moderator in 2018. The [comment cleanup mentioned above](/posts/comments/973014) was done by a different moderator in 2022 where all comments (at that time) were purged.